# "Cocoa Touch Application" Template from Xcode 3.1.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode-template

Just installed the latest SDK for iPhone 2.1. When I go to File -> New Project in Xcode, under the iPhone OS Application selection, I don't see a template icon for "Cocoa Touch Application". Am I missing something? Anything else I need to download other than the iPhone SDK? If not, how do I add it to the "iPhone OS Application" templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add any templates, this is what happens by default.

The closest thing to a normal Cocoa Touch application would be the Window-Based application as it gives you a window and a delegate...

The others, like Martin said, have different styles already applied to them... OpenGL, Navigation Controllers, Views, etc.

Answer (score 4):

OK, after some more digging, I found several posts which seem to indicate that the template names have been changed (from the apple support site).  So the problem is not with our templates, it is with the video tutorials - they have not been updated.  Here is the template mapping between old and new, best I can tell:

Cocoa Touch OpenGL Application -> OpenGL ES Application

Cocoa Touch Tab Bar -> Tab Bar Application

Cocoa Touch Utility -> Utility Application

Cocoa Touch Application -> Window-based Application / View based application

Cocoa Touch List -> Navigation based Application

Answer (score 2):

All the templates (under iPhone) are Cocoa based.

The difference between them is basically how you set up the main View and the navigational controls that are installed by default.